# using python: How can I convert given UT time to LST time Such that the function automatically increments day after 24 Hr check

Tags: python

I want to convert given Universal Time (UT)  to  Local Time (LT) . Such that the function automatically increments day after 24 Hr check. I tried various codes. I successfully converted time but unable to increment it by certain duration in a loop.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I'd recommend taking [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and then reading [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as an introduction to how SO works, and how to effectively ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> import pytz
>>> dt = datetime.utcnow()
>>> dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris'))
datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 28, 4, 44, 12, 778393, tzinfo=<DstTzInfo 'Europe/Paris' CEST+2:00:00 DST>)
>>> print(dt.astimezone(pytz.timezone('Europe/Paris')))
2019-05-28 04:44:12.778393+02:00
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks, I am new to python coding.I have tried a code to convert given Universal Time (UT) to Local Time (LT) that is working properly. But I want to increment date and time by a specified duration float (ex.1.036 seconds) in a loop from start LT time to end LT time. Such that day gets incremented after 24 Hrs.

Comment: startutc= '2019-03-25 14:26:18'....local_string1 = utc_str_to_local_str(startutc, utc_fmt, local_fmt).......ls1=datetime.strptime(local_string1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')...print(ls1)....2019-03-25 10:26:18.....I want something like this...But with date time incrementation in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

> > > I am new to python coding.I have tried below code to convert given Universal         Time  (UT) to Local Time (LT) that is working properly. But I want to increment date and  time by a specified duration float (ex.1.036 seconds) in a loop from start LT time to end LT  time. Such that day gets incremented after 24 Hrs.

```
>>>startutc= '2019-03-25 14:26:18' # Start UTC in String format
>>>endutc= '2019-03-26 14:26:18'   # End UTC in String format
>>>utc_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
>>>local_fmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
>>>local_string1 = utc_str_to_local_str(startutc, utc_fmt, local_fmt)
>>>local_string2 = utc_str_to_local_str(endutc, utc_fmt, local_fmt)
>>>ls1=datetime.strptime(local_string1, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') 
>>>ls2=datetime.strptime(local_string2, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
>>>t2= np.array([ls1+timedelta(seconds=i) for i in range(0,scans)]) 
>>>t = date2num(t2)

Using function I found somewhere on stack overflow:
>>>def utc_str_to_local_str(utc_str: str, utc_format: str, local_format: str):
"""
>>>:param utc_str: UTC time string
>>>:param utc_format: format of UTC time string
>>>:param local_format: format of local time string
>>>:return: local time string
>>>"""
>>>temp1 = datetime.strptime(utc_str, utc_format)
>>>temp2 = temp1.replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
>>>local_time = temp2.astimezone()
>>>return local_time.strftime(local_format)
```